# Publishing a Node Application

Tags: node.js, angular, publishing

I'm trying to understand how to properly publish a node application.  I have an angular 2 application which after build creates a www folder.   I've uploaded the folder to my hosting company which uses plesk for a control panel.

For non-angular applications I would point the node entry point to file which tells node where and how to start :

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  response.end('<H1>Hello World!</H1>');
}).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

I'm confused on what the entry point for an angular 2 application would be?
When I navigate to my `index.html` file it appear to serve the file and mostly work,  but shouldn't I have an entry point which is a js file?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly the problem is. Is it about Angular part or Node part? Angular doesn't need any special treatment, both html and js have to be served (and html should be served in a special way for HTML5 routing). You need a hosting to support Node, basically it should be VDS or something. *hosting company which uses plesk for a control panel* says literally nothing. If you've picked regular PHP hosting for Node app, then this was a mistake. I'd suggest to sort this out with hosting support.

Comment: @estus thanks for your response, I’m using a2hosting, on windows which comes with support for windows.  I’ve never published a node application they claim all applications which use node should have an entry point. I’m trying to figure out what file I should point to for the entry point, I’m not sure what the default is for an angular2 application or if it’s even needed at all

Comment: Depending on what's your plan on this hosting, this may or may not be possible. There are no regular 'entry points' in Node apps because usually you're the one who takes care of executing it as a daemon. This is very specific to your hosting, https://www.google.com/search?q=a2hosting+nodejs . There's no real need for Node in Angular app (as long as you're not after server side rendering). If you can configure server side to serve html and js files properly (with IIS, Apache, Nginx... whatever), this may work.

Comment: @estus, interesting, I thought angular was dependent on node, I wasn’t aware I could just have it served from IIS.  Thanks I think that answers my question, if you post that as an answer I’ll mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular applications need Node.js (NPM) to be installed and built, but after they are built, they don't depend on Node.js as web server - as long as SSR (server-side rendering, aka Angular Unversal) isn't needed.

Angular application can be served by any web server (IIS, Apache, Nginx, etc)  that was properly configured to serve SPA (single page application). If HTML5 routing is involved, this needs index file to be served for router path.